# How to pass an argument to a function in an event listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, arrow-functions

I am tackling a challenge, I am very new to JS and quite frankly I do not completely understand the challenge. 
The question I need to answer to move to the next stage is:

> Step 2 Create the following 3 functions:
>
> a displayBirthdate arrow function a displayPhone arrow function and a
>   displayAddress arrow function These functions will be called by event
>   listeners attached to buttons in the UI.
>
> Step 3 Create a displayExtraUserInfo arrow function. It should take in
>   a single parameter. It should then :
>
> Add a click listener to the BUTTON with id of btn-birthdate. The
>   listener should make a call to displayBirthdate and pass in the
>   parameter displayExtraUserInfo received
>
> Add a click listener to the BUTTON with id of btn-phone. The listener
>   should make a call to displayPhone and pass in the parameter
>   displayExtraUserInfo received
>
> Add a click listener to the BUTTON with id of btn-address. The
>   listener should make a call to displayAddress and pass in the
>   parameter displayExtraUserInfo received
>
> For the next 3 steps, be sure you have covered Step 1 above, then
>   review
>   https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6
>   for a primer on ES6 destructuring
>
> Step 4 Locate the displayBirthdate function you initially defined,
>   which took no parameter. Modify it to use object de-structuring to get
>   just the dob property of the parameter object it will receive.
>
> Step 5 Like in step 4, locate the displayAddress function and
>   de-structure its parameter to get just the location property
>
> Step 6 Like in step 4, locate the displayPhone function and
>   de-structure its parameter to get just the phone and cell properties

Here's my code:

```
var displayBirthdate = ({dob = 'DOB'}) => {};
var displayPhone = ({location = 'location'}) => {};
var displayAddress = ({phone = 'phone', cell='cell'}) =>{};

var displayExtraUserInfo = (params) => { 
      document.getElementById("btn-birthdate").addEventListener("click", function(){ displayBirthdate(params)});
      }
```

However, I am not getting it right, is there a problem with my logic? or code? i cannot tell what i am doing wrong.

Comment: *"I am not getting it right"*: Why do you think that? How did you test your function?

Comment: When you get the challenge right it automatically moves you to the next stage, right now, I get the error that I have "not created the click listener as specified" so I guessed I have a problem with my code somewhere.

Comment: You should maybe require that the matching element is a button. So `document.querySelector("button#btn-birthdate")`

Comment: I had done this but didn't get through

Comment: Now that I see the update of the question: it is clear you have not performed all the steps.

Comment: Okay. I, however, cannot figure out what I'm missing. spent all night looking through the lines. Now I have a headache

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? Check your code again. You used phone in place of address.

Comment: Yes, I have, I saw that yesterday. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve it cornelking

```
const displayExtraUserInfo = (param) => {
  document.querySelector('#btn-birthdate').addEventListener('click', () => {
    displayBirthdate(param);
  });
};
```

Comment: The arrow function at the end is the difference

Answer (score 1):

What I get from you question is that you want to call `displayBirthdate` on click and want to pass the `params` passed in `displayExtraUserInfo` to `displayBirthdate`

```js
var displayBirthdate = (params) => (console.log(params));
var displayPhone = ({location = 'location'}) => ({});
var displayAddress = ({phone = 'phone', cell='cell'}) =>({});

var displayExtraUserInfo = (params) => { 
      document.getElementById("btn-birthdate").addEventListener("click",
         function(){
             displayBirthdate(params)
         });
 }

displayExtraUserInfo('some data')
```

```html
<button id="btn-birthdate">click me</button>
```

Comment: Hi, I get this, but it still doesn't work. the arguments to be passed to `displayBirthdate ` `{dob = 'DOB'}` is a requirement. So I have to call the event listener as specified, then pass an object to the `displayBirthdate` arrow function

Comment: I have modified the question, does it help. i feel a little lost

Answer (score 1):

```
const displayExtraUserInfo = (params) => {
            document.getElementById("btn-birthdate").addEventListener("click", ()=> {
                displayBirthdate(params)
            })

           document.getElementById("btn-phone").addEventListener("click", () => {
                displayPhone(params)
            })
            document.getElementById("btn-address").addEventListener("click", () => {
                displayAddress(params)
            })

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for (Future Andelean) #winks

This is what you are looking for (Future Andelean) #winks

````
      const displayBirthdate = ({dob})=>{
        //
      }
      const displayPhone = ({phone, cell})=>{
        //
      }
      const displayAddress = ({location})=>{
        //
      }

      const displayExtraUserInfo = (param) => {
        document.querySelector('#btn-birthdate').addEventListener('click', () => {
          displayBirthdate(param);
        });

        document.querySelector('#btn-phone').addEventListener('click', () => {
          displayPhone(param);
        });

        document.querySelector('#btn-address').addEventListener('click', () => {
          displayAddress(param);
        });
      };```
````